# How shall the word "biology" be interpreted, if no English word can start with two stressed syllables?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

I am little confused over this matter; the teacher has stated that *no English word can start with two stressed syllables* and that *you understand a syllable is stressed when it's not reduced to a schwa and when it is therefore a full vowel*. For words like biology (/baɪˈɒl.ə.dʒi/), it seems that the PRICE vowel /aɪ/ is followed by the LOT vowel /ɒ/. It makes 2 full vowels followed by each other and contradicts the first information of the teacher.

Is there something I am missing?

The teacher considers *aɪ* an unstressed syllable.

> [image: screenshot]

The cambridge dictionary also considers it as being unstressed: /baɪˈɒl.ə.dʒi/ and not **/ˌbaɪˈɒl.ə.dʒi/**.

Comment: You're missing something (and possibly your teacher is, too). English syllables can have primary stress, secondary stress, or be unstressed.

Comment: Yes, but what he was telling is that no english word can have two stressed/unstressed syllable in the beginning. He considers /aɪ/ as an unstressed syllable. It confuses me

Comment: No English word starts with two syllables that both have primary stress. (And in fact, there is almost always only one primary stress per word.) There are three levels of stress here, not just two.

Comment: I edited the post ; If there were 3 levels, the cambride dictionary would have transcripted it as /,baɪˈɒl.ə.dʒi and not /baɪˈɒl.ə.dʒi/, wouldn't they ?

Comment: There are (at least) two different ways of analyzing stress in English words. If you say there are only two levels of stress, then some unstressed syllables have full vowels.

Comment: What the statement means to me is that if there are two primary stressed syllables in a row, there are two words.

Comment: Your teacher seems to be mixing two different systems of analyzing stress in English. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Degrees_of_lexical_stress).

Comment: There are plenty of English words that start with two equally stressed syllables: *tutu*, for example. There are no really fixed “rules” in English, merely conventions.

Comment: Did you really mean to write [wovel](https://www.peoplepoweredmachines.com/wovel/wovel_accessory.htm) or was it a typo ?

Comment: @GlobalCharm The second syllable of *tutu* is not stressed. Compare *canoe* and *tutu*, or *a two two* and *a tutu* where the former is a second class degree.

Comment: Anyone trying to arbitrarily force language into a mold will be frustrated by an unending list of exceptions.

Answer (score 24):

"No English word can start with two stressed syllables" is just false, unless you define "stressed syllable" as "primary-stressed syllable", in which case it is trivially true (because by definition a word only contains one primary-stressed syllable).

A better rule is that no English word can start with two *fully unstressed* syllables (two syllables with a reduced vowel).

As you have found, it's definitely the case that an English word can start with two syllables with unreduced vowels. Some theories of English stress allow unstressed syllables to contain unreduced vowels (at least in some circumstances), while other theories of English stress treat any syllable with an unreduced vowel as having at least some degree of stress (theories may make use of a concept of secondary or even tertiary levels of stress).

Comment: Here's a reference disagreeing with the statement ending the first paragraph: << Some words have optional stress. The following words may have two primary stresses each or one. Where there is one, it shall fall on the second syllable.

 'Ju- 'ly or Ju-'ly /    'bam- 'boo or bam-'boo / 
 'four-'teen or four-'teen /   'fif-'teen or fif-'teen / 
 'Car-'lisle or Car-'lisle [[Anna University](https://www.annauniv.edu/netlish/word_stress.htm)] Checking, M-W allows ...

Comment: for the  'double' or 'no' primary stress pronunciation of _bamboo_ (among others). In maths, it is possible to have two 'most popular / frequent' intervals, in a *bimodal* distribution. So, correspondingly, here it is necessary to give confirmation either that 'bamboo' can be said (in one pronunciation) to have no primary stress, or double primary stress. _You know about the need to add supporting references_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It always has a primary stress.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would be very interested to hear a native English speaker (from a primarily English speaking country) use one of those words in a sentence without stressing one syllable. When I try it, it feels like I am singing.

Comment: @piojo: How do you feel about two-word spondees, such as *true blue* or *why not*?

Comment: @ruakh Interesting. In my mind _true blue_ sounds like perfectly equal emphasis unless it comes at the end of a phrase. But it seems to fit into the same mental category as when adjectives are strung together, as in _the tall thin young woody chute_, where even the two syllable word "woody" receives almost no syllable emphasis. I'm not linguistically educated, but it seems as though English chained adjectives have their emphasis stripped. Similarly, _why not_ has equal emphasis (to my ears) unless it's at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @piojo I've been rehearsing 'July', and find I naturally (ie trying not to allow artificial elements related to the testing to intrude) pronounce it differently in different strings. In a naturally trailing-off sentence (eg a resigned "It won't be ready until the end of July", I certainly primary-stress the second syllable. But in a brisk, free-running  "They're at their best in June, July and August" there's no perceptible difference in stress.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only hard and fast rule in English is that there are no hard and fast rules.  (I suspect this sounds sarcastic, but I'm not really joking.)

Answer (score 13):

You're conflating two things. Stress and vowel reduction.
I too pronounce the word as /baɪˈɒl.ə.dʒi/; the only stressed syllable being the second one. The only reduced vowel is the third one. The first and fourth syllables are neither stressed nor reduced.

I believe what your teacher meant by "you understand a syllable is stressed when it's not reduced to a schwa and when it is therefore a full vowel" is that a stressed syllable is never reduced, but this does not imply the inverse, that a non-stressed syllable is always reduced. Indeed just the words "always" and (albeit not always!) "reduced" disprove this!

Comment: I'd say there's secondary stress on the first syllable. The last syllable, though unstressed, still has an unreduced vowel too, though.

Comment: I can't rank stress (1st two syllables)  in the 'US pronunciation' sample offered by [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/biology).  Your 'I too pronounce the word as /baɪˈɒl.ə.dʒi/; the only stressed syllable being the second one. The only reduced vowel is the third one. The first and fourth syllables are neither stressed nor reduced.' seems to imply that what you say is gospel.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nothing is gospel—I intended only to provide my own speech as an anecdotal example. The question has also been edited, so now my response appears a bit repetitious of what was asked. :-/

Comment: The best answers on ELU carry supporting evidence, linked and attributed quotes from researchers of acknowledged pedigree. Of course, there's often disagreement even at this level.

Answer (score -1):

Bi **OL** o gy has one stressed syllable.  You may think there are two because of the natural way the bi is pronounced makes it sound louder than certain other letter pairs when they are pronounced.

Comment: I can't rank stress (1st two syllables)  in the 'US pronunciation' offered by [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/biology).

Comment: Not sure what the problem is.  The word is pronounced as shown in the answer above.  UK and other countries may be influenced by their native languages to pronounce English words differently than what is correct in US.

Comment: ELU is not US-specific. And ELU expects answers to be backed by supporting references.

Comment: No English word has two stressed syllables next to each other.